# How can I use GCP NFS Filestore on k8 cluster with TPUs?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, tpu, gcsfuse, google-cloud-filestore

I'm using GKE to run K8 workloads and want to add TPU support.  [From GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/kubernetes-engine-setup#create-run-job), I "need" to attach a GCS bucket so the Job can read models and store logs.  However, we already create shared NSF mounts for our k8 clusters.  How hard of a requirement is it to "need" GCS to use TPUs?  Can shared Filestore NFS mounts work just fine?  What about using GCS Fuse?

I'm trying to avoid having the cluster user know about the back end file system (NFS vs GCS), and just know that that the files they provide will be available at "/home/job".  Since the linked docs show passing a `gs://mybucket/some/path` value as needed for file system parameters, I'm not sure if a `/home/job` value will still work.  Does the TPU access the filesystem directly and is only compatible with GCS?  Or do the nodes access the filesystem (preferring GCS) and then share the data (in memory) with the TPUs?

I'll try it out to learn the hard way (and report back), but curious if others have experience with this already.

Comment: I understand that you want to use TPU in your GKE cluster that has a NFS filestore, I found this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/kubernetes-engine-setup#auth-storage) that could help you do that. In the same guide there is a section that says ```Authorize Cloud TPU to access your Cloud Storage bucket``` that could help you with the bucket part, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Robertocd_98. I had seen that article and it didn't help with using Filestore - it only mentioned using GCS for shared storage.  Do Cloud TPUs truly _need_ GCS for files or can they access FileStore shares?

Comment: I don't think that that TPU needs GCS, in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/storage-buckets#storage_access) says that GCS is an option for storing your machine learning data of Cloud TPU, I try the guide that I post earlier and I was able to create the cluster with the TPU configuration and I didn't create a bucket to do it